# How to flush the dirty pages of OS file cache to disks?

Tags: linux, file, caching

Linux exploits remaining memory for its file cache

In my application (written in C++), I'd like to flush the dirty pages to disks explicitly from time to time
(Using O_DIRECT is not appropriate for me)

I tried fflush(), but it seems not what I wanted

Is there any way to flush the dirty pages of OS file cache to disks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sync_file_range()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync_file_range.2.html) to encourage flushing on Linux but confusingly **you can't use `sync_file_range()` to guarantee file durability/data integrity** - it is simply a hint that might help get flushing underway (see this Linux Plumbers Conference 2019 video of [Postgres developer Andres Freund complaining about the `sync_file_range()`'s manpage and the reply from filesystem developer Jan Kara](https://youtu.be/-oP2BOsMpdo?list=PLVsQ_xZBEyN30ZA3Pc9MZMFzdjwyz26dO&t=6616)). In short: it can help trigger flushing but you'll need to add/use something else to know durability.

I believe all the usual file descriptor `sync` style calls ([`fsync()`, `fdatasync()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fdatasync.2.html) etc.) also hint that you want writeback to start occurring but in a more heavy handed fashion compared to `sync_file_range()` (because they also force flushing of device non-volatile caches too)...